# set top,bottom padding on textview with wrap_content

Tags: android

```
  viewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            viewParams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 0);
  TextView text = new TextView(mContext);
  text.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
  text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
  text.setPadding(50,50,50,50);
  text.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.exp_comments));
```

I want my textview to have top and bottom padding. 
I set background with green-rectangular border around the textview.

I set height with wrap_content. 
and it means that the border is just above the text. 
I want to increase the top and bottom gap between the border and the text. 
So, I tried with setPadding() and setPaddingRelative() method. 
But it doesn't work....

Answer (score 1):

The `setPadding` method values is in pixels. You should convert your dp to pixels and then set the padding.

```
int valueInDp = 50;
Resources r = getResources();
int px = (int) TypedValue
    .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
text.setPadding(px,px,px,px);
```

Comment: when I tried to set the padding with the code above, left and right worked fine. the problem is that top and bottom padding is not working. I think it has something to do with  'wrap_content' on height. But I don't know exactly why.....

Comment: I think it is something in your layout, The view is dependent by other thing in the layout and it cant add bottom and top margins. Send me a screenshot or code how your layouts look

Answer (score 0):

Change top and bottom padding,

```
    text.setPadding(50,100,50,100);
```